# Deploy Spring application in STS

Tags: spring

During start up of a simple Spring application deployed in STS, I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader
```

In my context.xml, I have:

```
<Loader
loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"
useSystemClassLoaderAsParent="false" />
```

Do I need to put the following jar in a particular location?
I tried to copy it in various lib dirs in my STS install dir

```
spring-instrument-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar needs to be on your classpath.  Adding it to your project's build path should be all you need to get it working.

Comment: After looking into spring-instrument-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar it looks like that class isn't in there, according to jarfinder.com there is a jar named spring-tomcat-weaver that should contain it.

Comment: Thx, I'll see where that is and copy it to a lib and see if that works